# Doctrine mapping type entity to id, id to entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

As I said in the title, I want to convert an object to an ID (int/string) and backwards from ID to an object. Usually I would work with entity relations, but in this case I do not know the other entity/bundle and it should work independant.

I guess, I could use doctrine mapping types for that, but how can I inject my custom entity loader? So maybe I can use a callback for fetching the data.

Thats my idea (pseudocode):

```
class User {
    public function getId() { return 'IAmUserBobAndThisIdMyId'; }
}

class Meta {
    private $user;  // <== HERE I NEED THE MAGIC
    public function setUser($user) { $this->user = user; }
}

$user = new User();
$meta = new Meta();
$meta->setUser($user);
$em->persist($meta);  // <== HERE THE MAPPING TYPE SHOULD CONVERT THE ENTITY
```

Know I want the entity in my database like that: `user:IAmUserBobAndThisIdMyId`

And backwards:

```
$meta = $repository->findOneById(1);  // HERE I NEED THE MAGIC AGAIN
$user = $meta->getUser();
echo $user->getId();

// output: IAmUserBobAndThisIdMyId
```

So far, so easy... But now I need some logic and database access to restore that entity. The loading is easy, **but how can I inject that into my mapping type class**?

I read the [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html) and I was wondering, if I could use the event manager I get from `AbstractPlatform $platform` via parameter. Or is there maybe a better way?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what is what you what to accomplish that you can't. In your "pseudo-code", you are passing a `User` instance to `$meta`. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you read my questions below that? I need that "magic" that converts the database value `user:IAmUserBobAndThisIdMyId` into an entity and I am looking for a nice way to inject this "magic" into my mapping type object.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I'm asking because it's not clear, not because I haven't read. It is still not clear. I would advise to edit your code so it's clear what you want to happen, because so far it's not obvious. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You! I've edited my question. I think it is not so hard, but I want to avoid ugly hacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but i did not test this. Also you can use doctrine postLoad and postPersist/postUpdate events to transform your User entity to integer and back.

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        types:
            user: App\Doctrine\DBAL\Type\UserType
        ...
```

UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\DBAL\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Entity\User;

class UserType extends IntegerType
{
    const NAME = 'user';

    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
       $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $this->userRepository->find($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof User) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid value");
        }

        return $value->getId();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but the constructor of the base class is "final". so I cannot use it for dependency injection. I'll try DI over setter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a proper solution without hacking any classes to inject some service. The type mapping class fires an event and the conversion is handled outside.

```
class EntityString extends Type
{
    // ...

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $this->dispatchConverterCall($platform, TypeMapperEventArgs::TO_PHP_VALUE, $value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $this->dispatchConverterCall($platform, TypeMapperEventArgs::TO_DB_VALUE, $value);
    }

    protected function dispatchConverterCall(AbstractPlatform $platform, $name, $value)
    {
        $event = new TypeMapperEventArgs($name, $value);
        $platform->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent(TypeMapperEventArgs::NAME, $event);

        return $event->getResult();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Probably there are some better solutions, but for the moment that code does what I need. ;-)